# Xcode 6: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting an error when trying to build my app, and i'm not sure how to fix it.

I don't know if it is related, but I previously had an error about a missing "ProjectName-Prefix.pch" file. After a while of trying to figure that out, i finally fixed it, and it instead gave me this new error:

> Ld /Users/ethanhumphries/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACT_SMA-bfiknmwltajohybyhnbitrxfgsnv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACT\ SMATests.xctest/ACT\ SMATests normal x86_64
>       cd "/Users/ethanhumphries/Documents/Xcode Projects/ACT SMA"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/ethanhumphries/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACT_SMA-bfiknmwltajohybyhnbitrxfgsnv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ethanhumphries/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACT_SMA-bfiknmwltajohybyhnbitrxfgsnv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/ethanhumphries/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACT_SMA-bfiknmwltajohybyhnbitrxfgsnv/Build/Intermediates/ACT\ SMA.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACT\ SMATests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ACT\ SMATests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/ethanhumphries/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACT_SMA-bfiknmwltajohybyhnbitrxfgsnv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BlogReader.app/BlogReader -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework XCTest -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ethanhumphries/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACT_SMA-bfiknmwltajohybyhnbitrxfgsnv/Build/Intermediates/ACT\ SMA.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACT\ SMATests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ACT\ SMATests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ethanhumphries/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACT_SMA-bfiknmwltajohybyhnbitrxfgsnv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ACT\ SMATests.xctest/ACT\ SMATests
>
> ld: file not found: /Users/ethanhumphries/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ACT_SMA-bfiknmwltajohybyhnbitrxfgsnv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BlogReader.app/BlogReader
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It is telling me that the final line is where it is failing, at the:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950653/file-not-found-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-in-xcode-4-5-1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665196/ld-file-not-found-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invoca)?  I could go on, but you can just type "xcode ld: file not found:" into google.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i hadn't found that solution when looking, i managed to fix it by deleting and recreating my scheme