# SwiftUI Preview - Failed to Build Scheme, No such module "ProjectName"

Tags: swift, xcode, testing, swiftui, preview

I am trying build a `Preview` for a project that is built on `SwiftUI`. At first, I created the project with the name 'VOIP'. After some development and time, I connected it to the `AppStore Connect` and the name of the project was created differently, Let's say `VoipApp`. I can build the project into simulator or a device without any problem, however when I try to preview a `SwiftUI` `View`, it says `No such module VOIP` at project navigator. But as I said it just happens when I try to preview.

Here is the diagnostics;

```
no such module \'VOIP\'

----------------------------------------

SchemeBuildError: Failed to build the scheme "VOIP"

no such module 'VOIP'

Compile /Users/myuser/Projects/VOIP/VOIPTests/VOIPTests.swift:
/Users/myuser/Projects/VOIP/VOIPTests/VOIPTests.swift:10:18: error: no such module 'VOIP'
@testable import VOIP
             ^
```

I tried some answers from the network, but neither of them have been worked.

Comment: Do you have `VOIPTests.swift`? Is it really `import VOIP` there? Did you try to remove some of those, or both? Preview uses pre-built caches heavily - did you try to force clean everything, physically, like DerivedData, etc?

Comment: Of course I do and there is. I did try to force clean but not the derived data.

Comment: If it is there then why? Why don't remove it? You changed main app module name, so should rename it everywhere previous was used - it is not done automatically.

Comment: I did not changed the module name, my employer created it with a different name on app store connect and when changed the team to get provisioning profiles it changed automatically. I mean my projects name still the same, which is `VOIP`, on my local. However I install it to simulator or a device the is as appearing as at the app store connect name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26326618/1404324 this answer solved my issue. I just removed the scheme and created new one with new name.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493737/swiftui-preview-failed-to-build-scheme-no-such-module-projectname#comment107019070_60493737) about recreating the scheme did not work for me. However, I found that I was able to change the module name to the value expected by SwiftUI by editing the "Product Module Name" setting:

[image]

Comment: This was the solution for me. I have 3 different schemas and build configurations, and the SwiftUI preview stopped working once added. Setting the "Product module name" as the project name solved the problem

Comment: This didn't solved my issue.

Comment: I had various build target that all had differents names, just modifying this to have the same Product Module Name solved it for me 

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the pods and add my libraries through "Package Dependencies", it's show preview.

Answer (score -2):

try "Xcode > Product > Clean Build Folder"。

Comment: Be more explanative and make code snippet into Xcode > Product...